# Access: best way to temporarily copy a value between two forms

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a database with a snapshot type continuous form (let's call it *frmC*) whose record source is a query with multiple tables, plus another dynaset type modal form (let's call it *frmE*) that allows to edit the part of *frmC* information that comes from a single table. As a simplified example, imagine *frmC* contains *ProductCost* from *tblProducts*, *OrderQty* from *tblOrders*, while *frmE* allows for editing of *ProductCost* only and has record source *tblProducts* only. A button in *frmC* opens *frmE* with WHERE = the selected record in *frmC*.

Inside *frmE*, I wish to also display information from *frmC*, and use that information for temporary calculations that do not need to be stored (again, simplifying imagine that when increasing *ProductCost* I want the user to be able to see what the total impact of the increase would be considering the *OrderQty*).

At the moment I have come up with two different ways to accomplish this:

1. Adding an unbound locked control in *frmE* (e.g. *txtOrderID*) and using a macro connected to the button in *frmC* to SetValue *frmE!txtOrderID*=*frmC!OrderQty*
2. Adding a bound locked control in *frmE*, with source *frmC!OrderQty*

These both work fine, but I am wondering if either is a better choice or if there is any potential issue with any of these that I have not thought about.

As a note, the reason *frmE*'s record source is not the same query as *frmC* but rather a single table is because I'm following a suggestion to avoid keeping a dynaset type connection open to multiple tables when, such as this case, it is not strictly necessary for data input. If you disagree, I would love to hear more about it.

Comment: Read this post [VBA for passing a value from one form to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462876/msaccess-2003-vba-for-passing-a-value-from-one-form-to-another) carefully. Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, I had a read and I think I understand what is being proposed in that thread. However, I am trying to keep as much of my code in macros rather than VBA as I'm the only one in my organization with (very limited) knowledge of VBA and I think that macros will be easier to maintain long-term. In that case, I see that my solution n.2 is also mentioned in the thread that you linked, although I do understand that will tightly bind the two forms together (which is fine by me in this case, I do not plan to reuse it anywhere else). Am I missing anything?

Comment: A potential issue is what happens when the user closes or opens a form that is involved in the calculations.  So usually I create properties (getters and setters around a hidden global variable(s)).  I put the setters and getters as public functions (must be functions) in a code module.  Access intellisense can find public functions in code modules.  So we get the benefits of encapsulation.  When the user opens a key form we get the property for saved and default values.  When the user closes the form we set the property so other forms can still use the value.